# Error message when using \si{} in \begin{equation} environment

Tags: siunitx

For some reason I get an "Undefined Control Sequence" error message when using the following command:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts]
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation} \label{compressiondb}
c = 1 - \frac{\text{d} P_\text{out} [\si{\decibe}]}{\text{d} P_\text{in}[\si{\decibel}]}\,.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Typo #1: mismatched delimiters: `\usepackage{amsfonts]`

Comment: Typo #2: misspelled macro: `\decibe`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to typos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Typo: mismatched delimiters: `\usepackage{amsfonts]`

The compilation error `Runaway argument?` is usually a giveaway for unmatched  delimiters.

2. Typo: misspelled macro: `\decibe`

The error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \decibe
```

tells you exactly where the problem lies, or at least what to search for.

3. Commenters rightly indicate that `\text` should not be used to change math to the upright style.  Use `\mathrm` instead, as reflected in the revised MWE.

Fixing those makes it compile.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation} \label{compressiondb}
c = 1 - \frac{\mathrm{d} P_\mathrm{out} [\si{\decibel}]}{\mathrm{d} P_\mathrm{in}[\si{\decibel}]}\,.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great, thx so much!

Comment: 3 `\text` should definitely not be used like that, better use `\mathrm` or similar. Misuse of the `\text` command is sadly very common